# How to enable GPU rendering in Python Gtk3 in Windows?

Tags: python, opencv, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I noticed that Gtk in Windows seems to be rendering images using the CPU rather than the GPU (whereas in Linux this does not seem to be the case).

I am creating a program using Python, Gtk3, and OpenCV which streams video from a camera and displays it in a GtkImage. The program works but the moment I resize the image to a larger resolution, the framerate seems to drop. I notice that the CPU usage is higher, the larger the image is.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, GLib

# This method is called in a thread that read() frames from cv2.VideoCapture and displays it into a GtkImage.
def writeDisplay(uiBuilder, frame):
    # Load frame from OpenCV into pixbuf
    frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    h, w, d = frame.shape
    pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(
        frame.tostring(), GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, w, h, w*d)

    # Load image into GtkImage
    imageDisplay = uiBuilder.get_object("display")
    GLib.idle_add(imageDisplay.set_from_pixbuf, pixbuf)
    pass
```

In Linux, I don't notice any frame drop which suggests that GtkImage is rendered by the GPU. However, in Windows it seems to be software rendered.

I should also note that I am using [PyGObject in Windows using Msys2](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-getting-started).

Is there any way of streaming video frames from OpenCV to a Gtk3 GUI using hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK3 always uses the CPU to render, regardless of the platform. The only way to use the GPU to render something in GTK3 is through the [`GtkGLArea` widget](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.GLArea.html), where you have access to a GL context.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that might be the case. Do you have any examples of displaying an image in GtkGLArea (preferably an OpenCV frame)?

I have been googling endlessly and I cannot seem to get an image to show up.

Comment: I have noticed that a simple:
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

call will result in OpenGL throwing an 1280 error when trying to render within an GtkGLArea.

Comment: You don't need to enable GL_TEXTURE_2D: that's an old value for the fixed function pipeline in GL 1. You are probably using or referencing some very old OpenGL documentation. GTK defaults to the GL 3.2+ core contexts. See: https://community.khronos.org/t/getting-gl-invalid-enum-when-calling-glenable-gl-texture-2d/72631 As for OpenCV: sorry, I never used it, so I'm unable to help you with that.

Comment: Is there any way to use an older GL 2.1 context that supports glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)?

I tried this: but it does not work
area = Gtk.GLArea()
area.set_required_version(2, 1)

Comment: No, there is no way to ask for a legacy GL 2.1 context; at worst, you can get a 3.0. Nobody should really be using OpenGL pre-3.2. You can find decent tutorials that do not involve writing GL code from 20 years ago.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. The answer I posted here with the entire fixed code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586457/how-to-render-opencv-frames-in-opengl-3-2-gtkglarea-in-python/75598170